# Javascript Rowsets

Tags: javascript

Trying to generate a table from some data I am getting. 
it seems to be alright until i hit the

```
html += "<td>" + data.rowsets[0].rows[i].Header[u] + "</td>";
```

This wont work: Error message 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I have even tried with an index for the column

```
html += "<td>" + data.rowsets[0].rows[i].[u] + "</td>";
```

But when i am entering directly the column name, then it works.

```
html += "<td>" + data.rowsets[0].rows[i].ID + "</td>";
```

The data i am getting is build like this.

Object

- Data

-- Rowsets

--- Colmns

--- Rows

```
var ArTable = {

//Takes the header as first row.
generate: function (data, headerdata) {
    //Storing the HTML
    var html = "<table>";

    //Getting all the header Data
    var Header = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.rowsets[0].columns.length; i++) {
        Header.push(data.rowsets[0].columns[i].name);
    }

    //Header
    if (headerdata == true) {
        html += "<thead></tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.rowsets[0].columns.length; i++) {
            html += "<td>" + data.rowsets[0].columns[i].name + "</td>";
        }
        html += "</tr></thead>"
    }
    //The Body
    html += "<tbody>"
    for (var i = 0; i < data.rowsets[0].rows.length; i++) {
        html += "<tr>"
        for (var u = 0; u < Header.length; u++) {
            console.log(Header[u]);
            html += "<td>" + data.rowsets[0].rows[i].Header[u] + "</td>";
        }
        html += "</tr>"
    }
    html += "</tbody></table>"
    return html;
}
}
```

how can you get the data without knowing the column name before handed?

Comment: Did you mean `data.rowsets[0].rows[i][Header[u]]`?

Comment: Have you tried with 

`html += "<td>" + data.rowsets[0].rows[i][Header[u]] + "</td>";`

Comment: This worked. if you post it as an answer i can mark it.!